# How do I convert object to string in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-server

I am very new to node js. I am trying to create a simple coap client and server using node js. I could create a server on which a text file resides.
I want to access that from the client.

```
var coap = require('coap');
var str = "";
var req = coap.request("coap://localhost:5683");
req.on("response", function(chunk){
    str +=chunk;    
    console.log(str);   
    chunk.pipe(process.stdout);
});
```

This code is giving me the output as [object Object]. How do I get the string form of this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to do that. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) the documentation.

Comment: Using JSON.stringify is also giving me the same output. :(

Comment: Wait. Is that chunk a node buffer? My fault, I didn't get it before. Is it?

Comment: yes it is. Its a chunk of data from the file on the server.

Comment: What does the file contain? If you want to parse an object read from that file, you have to write something there that makes sense...

Comment: Its is simple text file

Comment: If you have a json object written into the file, you should use `JSON.parse` (not `JSON.stringify`) on the resulting string after you have read it. Have you read the documentation above?

Answer (score 0):

**for general purpose :**
`JSON.stringify(obj);`

**if object includes functions :**
`require("util").inspect(obj);`

read it here : https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/how-to-use-util-inspect/